# Parameters between screens in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I need to pass a game's score from level one to level two in javafx so that it can accumulate but I can't find a way.

```
private void faseDos() {

    try {
        
        // Cargo la vista
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/vista/NivelDos.fxml"));

        // Cargo el padre
        Parent root = loader.load();

        // Obtengo el controlador
        NivelDosController controlador = (NivelDosController)loader.getController();

        // Creo la scene y el stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage stage = new Stage();

        // Asocio el stage con el scene
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        // Indico que debe hacer al cerrar
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> controlador.recibeParametros(NivelUno, Temp.getText()));

        // Cierro la ventana donde estoy
        Stage actual = (Stage) this.levelUp.getScene().getWindow();
        actual.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NivelUnoController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

@FXML

public void recibeParametros (NivelUnoController NivelUno, String puntaje)

{
        
    System.out.println("Puntos a recibir = "+ puntaje);
            
    Temp.setText(puntaje);
            
    NivelUno_en_NivelDos = NivelUno;
    
}
```

Comment: [mcve] ... and stick to java naming conventions please

Comment: As you load a separate fxml file for lvl 2, I suppose there are 2 Controller Classes. If you don't have some LevelManager, you will initiate loading the second level from the first level. This is when you want to call a setter like (setPoints) on the new controller. (BTW you can put your fxml loading code in the ctor of the controller, and call setController(this) within the constructor, which makes instantiating much easier)